# new dynamic allocation vs normal allocation

Tags: c++

what's the difference between these two methods?

```
Method(CustomClass t)
{
CustomClass *temp = &t;
}
```

called like this

```
Method(CustomClass(1,2,3));
```

and

```
Method(CustomClass* t)
{
CustomClass *temp = t;
}
```

called like this

```
Method(new CustomClass(1,2,3));
```

i haven't coded in c++ for a few years now and am having some trouble remembering. I'm coming from c# where every class need to be dynamically allocated with 'new'. The thing is that i don't undertand the difference between alocating an object dynamically with 'new' and calling it normally. How does temp differ in the 2 examples?

More specific example: I was creating a linked list and for my list i had this method:

```
void List::AddNew(TestClass node)
{
    if (!first)
    {

        first = &node;
    }
    else
    {
        bool setFirst = false;
        if (!last)
            setFirst = true;

        TestClass *temp;
        temp = last;
        last = &node;

        if (temp)
        temp->next = last;

        if (setFirst)
        first->next = last;
    }


}
```

where `first` and `last` are `TestClass *`; the list wasn't initialized correctly (first and last pointed to the same value) and i had no idea why, so i changed the method to this:

```
void List::AddNew(TestClass* node)
{
    if (!first)
    {

        first = node;
    }
    else
    {
        bool setFirst = false;
        if (!last)
            setFirst = true;

        TestClass *temp;
        temp = last;
        last = node;

        if (temp)
        temp->next = last;

        if (setFirst)
        first->next = last;
    }


}
```

and now it works. I'm missing a basic principle for pointers and i can't seem to guess that it is.

Here is TestClass also:

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    int x, y;
    TestClass *next;
    TestClass *prev;
    TestClass();
    TestClass(int,int);
    ~TestClass();

};
```

Answer (score 1):

> what's the difference between these two methods?

One of them is using stack (automatic) allocation, while the other is using heap (dynamic) allocation.

```
Method(CustomClass(1,2,3)); // stack based

Method(new CustomClass(1,2,3)); // heap based
```

If you're going to use `new` you need to make sure you `delete` that reference also. Otherwise, you'll have a memory leak.

> yes, i know this but what's the real defference between the
>   allocations and when should i use one or the other?

Object lifetime. If you put something on the stack, you will only be able to use it within a particular function, and any functions below it will need it passed as a parameter. If you put it on the heap, you can return a reference to it and use it wherever you want. You can't return a reference / address to a stack variable since it's life ends when the function returns.

Comment: yes, i know this but what's the **real** defference between the allocations and when should i use one or the other? why does my example work when i pass a dynamically allocated value and not when i pass a stack allocated one?

Comment: And you should make sure you don’t throw any exceptions before the `delete`, IOW use `std::unique_ptr` instead. (Or just take a `const&` really.)

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru object lifetime. If you put something on the stack, you will only be able to use it within a particular function, and any functions below it will need it passed as a parameter. If you put it on the heap, you can return a reference to it and use it wherever you want. You can't return a reference / address to a stack variable since it's life ends when the function returns.

Comment: but i can get a pointer to a stack based alloc object, doesn't the object stay accesible this way? i.e. SomeClass *a = &someClassStackAlloc;

Comment: Only within the scope of the stack frame it was created in.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're most confused about when to use dynamic-allocation vs when to use stack-allocation. The only thing to know is that you should use stack-based allocation when there is no need for dynamic-based allocation. When is dynamic- (or heap) allocation needed you ask? Well, normally you would use it when you need an object to exist beyond the scope in which it was created or when the contents of that dynamically-allocated object rely on a strictly runtime mechanism (like the addition of elements to a vector (the size may not be known at compile-time)). Also, this...

```
T* t = &t;
```

Is not heap-allocation. This is simply a pointer with automatic-storage duration (on the stack) pointing to another object on the stack (if `t` is itself stack-based). Allocation on the heap happens only when `new` is used.

Answer (score 0):

CustomClass *temp;
temp is only a pointer. It points to NULL(ok, actually it can point everywhere, but you should set it to NULL if no object exists) or to a **already** existing class.

*CustomClass tmp;*
Creates a object.

Method(CustomClass* t):
Demands for a already existing Object (t = pointer to existing object).

CustomClass *temp = t;
Assigns the pointer to a new local pointer.

*Method(CustomClass t):*
Should create a copy of the class you pass (not sure...)

CustomClass *temp = &t;
& = Adress-Operator. Retrieves address of t and saves it to the local pointer temp.

mfg